# Relativistic invariants of a classical field in 4D fashion: why the relation between the components of the current density holds?

Tags: special-relativity, angular-momentum, conservation-laws, field-theory, covariance

I'm trying to understand how is justified the following relation between the first component of the current density integrated over the volume and the scalar product of the 4-vector current density and a hypersurface orthogonal to the $x^0$ axis
$$\int j^0 dV=\int j^\rho dS_\rho$$
Is introduced in "The Classical Theory of Fields: Volume 2 - Landau"(§14-§29-§32),
where it's written that is possible to write the total charge $\int \rho dV=\int j^0 dV$ in a four dimensional form $\int j^\rho dS_\rho$, where the integral is taken over the entire four-dimensional hyperlane perpendicular to the $x^0$ axis and this mens that the integration is performed over the whole 3D space and that in general the last integral over an arbitrary surface is the sum of the charges whose world lines pass through this surface.
The point that i'm still not getting is how the first component is related to the other 4 in this integral relation. I also precise that i encountered this problem evaluating the Noether's charge under Lorentz transformation of a field and finding that the angular momentum $M^{\mu\nu}$ (the Noether's conserved charge)can be expressed in a Lorentz-covariant form: $$M^{\mu\nu}=\int dV (x^\mu T^{0\nu}-x^\nu T^{0\mu})=\int dS_\rho (x^\mu T^{\rho\nu}-x^\nu T^{\rho\mu})$$ In these last lines, mathematically, the problem is the same becuse i'm not getting how the zero-$\nu$ component integrated over the volume is equal to all the 4 component multiplied for these 4 hypersurfaces.

Comment: I think you should use the continuity equation.

Comment: This property is shown before introducing the continuity equation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of $dS^i$ (Landau §6) is that it is a four-vector equal in magnitude and normal to the hypersurface element; in other words, $dS^i$ is the projection of the hypersurface element, respectively, onto the hyperplanes $x^0=$ const, $x^1=$ const, $x^2=$ const and $x^3=$ const.

By definition, the integral

$\int_{x^0=\text{const.}} j^i dS_i$

is carried out for the hypersurface $x^0=$ const whose projections onto other three components are null, i.e., the only contribution to the above integral is

$\int_{x^0=\text{const.}} j^0 dS_0.$

The integral

$\int j^i dS_i$

over an arbitrary hypersurface is, of course, cannot be written only as integrations over $dS_0$; in this case, the integral describes the sum of all charges whose world lines pass through this hypersurface (Landau §28).